# Nextjs middleware authentication is not working due to poor folder structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, next.js, middleware

My next app has two types of users(staff, and client) with separate directories and dashboards. I have placed middleware auth in each of these folders. But when a user visits the page `localhost:3000/staff` or `localhost:3000/client`, the dashboard flickers for a second and then redirects the user(staff or client) to their respective login pages. Any user can see what's on the dashboard without authentication. The authentication is based on local stored cookie (token).

With my basic understanding, I have arranged directories and files as follows:

```
├── app
│   ├── StoreProvider.tsx      
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── client
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── staff
│   │       └── page.tsx
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── ProtectedRoutes.tsx
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── router
│   │   │   ├── client
│   │   │   │   ├── ProtectedRoutes.tsx
│   │   │   │   └── routes.ts
│   │   │   └── staff
│   │   │       ├── ProtectedRoutes.tsx
│   │   │       └── staff-links.tsx
│   │   ├── features
│   │   │   ├── client
│   │   │   │   └── authSlice.ts
│   │   │   └── staff
│   │   │       └── authSlice.ts
│   │   ├── store.ts
│   ├── staff
│   │   ├── (overview)
│   │   ├── clients
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── middleware.ts
│   │   ├── projects
│   │   └── staff
│   ├── client
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── leads
│   │   ├── loading.tsx
│   │   ├── middleware.ts
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── reports
│   │   └── support
│   └── utils
│       ├── axios
│       │   └── axiosInstance.ts
│       └── services
│           ├── client
│           │   └── clientAPIServices.ts
│           └── staff
│               └── staffAPIServices.ts
```

In staff> middleware and client > middleware, I am checking if the staff/client token exists or not:

`staff ├── middleware.ts`
`client ├── middleware.ts`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { authRoutes, protectedRoutes } from '../lib/router/client/routes';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const currentUser = request.cookies.get('staff')?.value;

  if (
    protectedRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname) &&
    (!currentUser || Date.now() > JSON.parse(currentUser).expiredAt)
  ) {
    request.cookies.delete('user');
    const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/staff', request.url));
    response.cookies.delete('staff');

    return response;
  }

  if (authRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname) && currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/staff', request.url));
  }
}
```

The protected routes job is to redirect the user if the cookie does not exist.

`lib ├── router ├── client ├── ProtectedRoutes.tsx`

`lib ├── router ├── staff  ├── ProtectedRoutes.tsx`

```
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

type Props = {};
export default function ProtectedRoutes({ children }: any) {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!Cookies.get('token')) {
      router.push('auth/staff');
    }
  }, [router]);
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

I have wrapped staff > layout.tsx and client > layout.tsx with ProtectedRoutes.

`staff ├── layout.tsx`

`client ├── layout.tsx`

```
'use client';

import ProtectedRoutes from '../lib/router/staff/ProtectedRoutes';
// import SideNav from '../../components/dashboard/sidenav';
import StaffMenu from '@/app/components/dashboard/staff-menu';

type Props = {};
export default function layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ProtectedRoutes>
      <div className="min-h-full">
        <StaffMenu />

        <main>
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            {children}
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </ProtectedRoutes>
  );
}
```

So far I have tried extracting the middleware into the app directory but middleware is not working on staff and clients. Secondly, I tried removing protected routes completely but now users can directly access the dashboard without authentication.